# Is the power Transition Life described in more detail anywhere?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, psionics

The *Dragon* #319 Dark Sun article "Setting and Races: Struggling to Survive in a Savage World" by David Noonan says, "Non-human elan are never created, and it could be that the *transition life* power simply doesn't work for any other creatures but those who were originally human" (21).

The psionic power *transition life* isn't described in the article. Can the power be found elsewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### No D&D product describes this psionic power

By a process of elimination, we can be reasonably certain that the power *transition life* is not described anywhere in any official source.

The Elan first appeared in the *Expanded Psionics Handbook* (April 2004), while Dragon #319 was published one month later (May 2004). **This rules out any release before 2004**.

The [D&D 4th edition compendium](https://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/database.aspx) reveals that the Elan appear only in the book *Psionic Power*, which does not reference any power called *transition life*, but only a ritual called the *rite of Awakening*, for which no game rules are provided. 5th edition has yet to release an official book on Dark Sun, psionics, or Elan, and Dragon magazine no longer exists. **This rules out any release after 2008.**

Neither the Wizards of the Coast 3.5-era website archive nor [Athas.org](http://www.athas.org) contain any reference to *transition life*, and WotC never released an official Dark Sun setting book for third edition. This eliminates all official D&D 3.5 sources except **Paizo-era magazines** and **WotC sourcebooks on psionics**.

[DragonDex](https://www.aeolia.net/dragondex/articles-subject.html) **eliminates all Dragon magazines**, except #319, which we already know doesn't describe the power. Dungeon Magazine #150 contains an index of all adventures, of which only four are set in Dark Sun, and of those the only issue in the third edition era is Dungeon #110, which does not describe the power in question. Dungeon #111, which has part 2 of Dungeon #110's Dark Sun monsters collection, also makes no mention of it. **This eliminates all Dungeon magazines.**

The only two remaining possible official sources are *Expanded Psionics Handbook* and *Complete Psionic*. **Neither book describes this power.**

We can therefore be reasonably certain that **no D&D product describes the *transition life* power.**

#### Why isn't the power described anywhere?

Both the *Expanded Psionics Handbook* and the Dragon #319 article were written by David Noonan. Both were released almost simultaneously, and contained very similar text regarding the Elan.

Dragon #319:

> Thus, elans do not reproduce biologically, but rather psionically, through the *transition life* power. Even then, their "children" are usually fully-grown adult humans. Non-human elans are never created, and it could be that the *transition life* power simply doesn't work for other creatures but those who were originally human.

*Expanded Psionics Handbook*:

> Thus, elans do not reproduce biologically, but rather psionically, through a mysterious psionic ritual known only to elans. Even then, their "children" are usually already fully-formed adult humans. Nonhuman elans are never created, and it could be that the ritual simply doesn't work for any creatures but those who were originally human.

The most plausible explanation for this difference is that the two race descriptions have the same author (Noonan), but different editors (WotC vs Paizo). The WotC editor removed the reference to the specific power, since there's no room in *Expanded Psionics Handbook* for powers that the player characters can't use, and it would be confusing to reference to a power that's not included in any book.

But Dragon, being a magazine and not a sourcebook, didn't have that mindset, and hadn't seen the *Expanded Psionics Handbook* before the issue was finalized for print, since they both came out at about the same time. Its editor couldn't have known that such a power didn't actually exist in the final *Expanded Psionics Handbook*.

Following these two releases, no product or article saw the need to issue a correction or elaborate on the highly secretive creation method of one race, and so the discrepancy remained unresolved thereafter.

Comment: This would be my assessment. I've actually looked through a few other psionics books too, like hyperconsious(though that one is Bruce R. Cordell's book), and it isn't there either. What I find amusing is how similar the Elan creation process sounds to how illithids are created.

Comment: Impressive digging!

Comment: I'll note, though, that elans and thus some way of creating them wasn’t a Dark Sun thing—which means there could have been non-Dark Sun 4e psionics material about them. Probably not, but it’s the one thing your answer doesn't seem to cover?

Comment: Searching the Compendium reveals that the Elan are referenced in one 4e psionics book, but the _transition life_ power doesn't appear in this book. Updated answer to reference this.

Comment: In 3.x, Elans also show up in Eberron.  They're danced over lightly enough that I wouldn't *expect* this power there, but it's an area you haven't covered in your otherwise impressively exhaustive trawl.

Comment: They might have a different justification/origin in Eberron, though.

Comment: Elan are briefly mentioned in _Secrets of Sarlona_ where they are Quori imprisoned in human bodies, but no reference is made to the specific power used.

Answer (score 4):

I am reasonably certain it is not.

Part of the whole point of the elan race is that they are part of this secretive, mystical cabal. Very, very few details about that cabal, particularly its upper echelons that actually do things like creating a new elan, are described—they are left up to the DM.

Creating a new elan is a matter of plot, and any rules for it (for instance, stats for a *transition life* power to do it) would only get in the way. There isn’t any particular reason to need stats for it, because it is up to the DM when, how, if, it happens. It is not something the players have access to.

We can surmise a few things about the power, though. It utterly wipes the memories and experiences of the subject, leaving a new elan. That implies that the subject is reset to 1st level—in fact, *just having gained* 1st level—, losing all skills, feats, class features, and so on, and being forced to choose those things anew as a new 1st-level character.

That implies some serious power going into this. [*Modify memory*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/modifyMemoryPsionic.htm) isn’t nearly that indelible, or that thorough. [*Psychic reformation*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/psychicReformation.htm) is that thorough and permanent, but to undo each and every thing  about the subject through *psychic reformation* would be exorbitantly expensive. But then, *psychic reformation* also includes, you know, reforming the subject, which doesn’t happen for new elans. So that’s something.

Beyond the mental components, which are probably more of an undesired *side effect* than the actual point of the power, we have substantial physical changes to the subject’s body—most notably biological immortality. Elans are aberrations without racial hit dice, so becoming one temporarily is within the purview of [*metamorphosis*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/metamorphosis.htm)—but that doesn’t get you any of its supernatural, psionic, or spell-like abilities, nor its extraordinary qualifies. Since actual elan have those, that implies something more like [*greater metamorphosis*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/metamorphosisGreater.htm), but as an intrinsic change to the creature rather than a temporary effect. (It is unclear if the biological immortality of elans is covered by *metamorphosis* or *greater metamorphosis*, but it’s also safe to say that abating aging for a few minutes is a whole lot easier than preventing it altogether, forever.)

So we are looking at a combination of effects more potent than any available for player manifesters. A 9th-level power clearly falls well short of producing an elan. In fact, for players, the only likely avenue for it is [*reality revision*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/realityRevision.htm)—but that probably isn’t how elans are generally made, since that would probably fall under perhaps the most dire warning in 3.5e:

> You can try to use *reality revision* to produce more powerful effects than these, but doing so is dangerous. The manifestation may pervert your intent into a literal but undesirable fulfillment or only a partial fulfillment.

Comment: Sounds like what happened to Arete, the First Elan.